# Show data from firestore two properties

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to show data which meets the following 2 conditions:

- The 'done' property is false, and
- If 'done' is true, then only show today's done items (serverTimeStamp)

How could I go about achieving this:

Currently I have the following which only returns items where 'done' is false.

```
yield* userDoc.todoCollection
        .orderBy('serverTimeStamp', descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .map(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.documents
              .map((doc) => TodoDto.fromFirestore(doc).toDomain()),
        )
        .map(
          (todos) => right<TodoFailure, KtList<TodoItem>>(
            todos
                .where(
                  (todo) =>
                      !todo.done,
                )
                .toImmutableList(),
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this condition in the `where` function:

```
!todo.done || (todo.done && (todo.time as DateTime).isAfter(DateTime(DateTime.now().year,DateTime.now().month,DateTime.now().day)))
```